# Large jsPDF file causes 504 Gateway Timeout

Tags: javascript, http, ionic-framework, jspdf

I am developing an Ionic mobile app written primarily in AngularJS and Javascript in which I generate a PDF file from user data in the client-side and send it to the server to be emailed to the user.

The PDF file generated using the jsPDF library is extremely large because it contains a table with a column of images (generated using the jsPDF autotable plugin). When I try to send the pdf data URI to the server, it immediately returns a 504 Gateway Timeout error in the console.

I have tried two methods:

- Saving the PDF as a datauristring and sending through url encoding

  ```
    var pdfBase64 = doc.output('datauristring');
    $http({
          method: "POST",
          url: 'https://www.myserver.com/api/export-events',
          params:
              {current_user: $rootScope.currentuser, 
              pdf: pdfBase64}
     }).then(function(data) {
         console.log(data);
         var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
             title: "Export Successful!",
             template: 'A PDF was sent to your email address.'
         });
  ```
- Saving the PDF as a blob and sending using FormData

  ```
     var pdfBase64 = doc.output('blob');
     var formData = new FormData();
     formData.append('current_user', $rootScope.currentuser);
     formData.append('pdf', pdfBase64);

      $http.post('https://www.myserver.com/api/export-events', formData, {
         transformRequest: angular.identity,
         headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
     }).then(function(data) {
         console.log(data);
         var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
             title: "Export Successful!",
             template: 'A PDF was sent to your email address.'
         });
     })
  ```

How can I send this large file to the server without causing a Gateway Timeout? Any help would be appreciated.